# Return an html table element's id, and parse the id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of elements and I want to be able to click a square in the table.  When I click on the square.  Each square is a 'td' element and it has a unique id.  I want to return the id 's id when I click it, and then I want to parse the id with another function.  This is what I am trying and it does not work.

```
td.onclick=function(){
          return td.id}
```

However it is a bit strange to me that this statement does work

```
td.onclick=function(){
              alert(td.id)}
```

Also, suppose I am able to return the td.id, I do not know how I would pass it to another function to parse it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us what you have in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: @Jeanluca Scaljeri I will try to do a jsfiddle.  I have never done it before.

Comment: Here test web site I have up [testsite](http://fri.cnm.utexas.edu/~fri/fridb/server.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call another function in the onclick.

```
td.onclick = function(){
   var eleID = this.id;
   someOtherFunction(eleID);
};

function someOtherFunction(id){
   //the element's id will be in the variable id
}
```

and since you are using jQuery you could do,

```
$("#myTableId td").click(function(){
   var eleID = this.id; //or $(this).id but no sense to wrap it to just get an id.
   someOtherFunction(eleID);
});
```

instead of setting each td element's onclick property individually.

Comment: the jQuery solution was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#table1 tr td").each(function(i,td)
      {
       $(td).click(function()
           {
             if($(this).attr("id")!=null)
              {
                alert($(this).attr("id"));
              }
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, think about where you are trying to send the string.  Call the function within the `onClick` function.

Instead of

```
td.onclick=function(){
          return td.id}
```

Which returns `td.id`, use `this.id`

```
td.onclick=function(){
              functionToCall(this.id)}
```